# Crystal Reports References Problem

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I am trying to create a report in visual studio 2010. I am using a crystal reports and visual studio 2010. I already added all the references with a component name of Crystal Reports. However, I do get a lot of errors and I don't know what other references should I add. Please help.

This is the screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well.. I'm not sure what to tell you. Maybe the references are not the same version that your code is expecting. Maybe you are missing some assemblies.

More information is needed about the code itself, what runtime you have installed and are trying to use.